# Lighting a menorah in a no-flame environment

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia

Many institutions where people sleep are no-flame environments.  For instance, hospitals have oxygen. Hotels have very sensitive smoke detectors.

How does one fulfill the mitzvah of lighting the menorah when in such a place?

(One year, I traveled on Chanukah and I lit outside the door of my hotel room, but that may not be possible for many hotels.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/electric-menorah

Comment: There opinions which allow one to use an incandescent light for these instances

Comment: How do you know there is way to do so?

Comment: see https://www.aish.com/atr/Electric_Menorah.html?s=fb